# How to convert between FixedLength and Delimited records?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm trying to read a fixed length file and convert it to a delimited file format for use in Excel. Using the FileHelpers library I'm able to read/write either of these formats, but I'm having trouble converting between them.

My closest approach is to declare an abstract class for the record where I declare the fields in, specify the order and use any Converters. Then from that abstract class, derive a class for the delimited record and the fixed length record. I manage to get this to work up until I try to create the fixed length engine, at which point I get an exception that apparently some of the attributes aren't taking.

Here's what I have so far:

```
void Main()
{   
    // Arrange
    var delimitedEngine = new FileHelperEngine<CustomerDelimitedRecord>();
    var fixedLengthEngine = new FileHelperEngine<CustomerFixedLengthRecord>();
    var input = @"C:\input.csv";
    var output = @"C:\output.csv";

    // Act
    var records = (CustomerRecord[]) delimitedEngine.ReadFile(input);
    fixedLengthEngine.WriteFile(output, (CustomerFixedLengthRecord[])records);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public abstract class CustomerRecord
{
    [FieldOrder(2)]
    public string Name;

    [FieldOrder(1)]
    public int ID;
}

[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class CustomerDelimitedRecord : CustomerRecord
{
}

[FixedLengthRecord]
public class CustomerFixedLengthRecord : CustomerRecord
{
    [FieldFixedLength(50)]
    public new string Name;

    [FieldFixedLength(5)]
    public new int ID;
}
```

This seems to not have any errors, but I get the following runtime exception:

> Bad Usage Exception
>
> The field: 'Name' must be marked the FieldFixedLength attribute
>   because the record class is marked with FixedLengthRecord.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, but I'm open to any suggestions. I feel this still wouldn't be the best solution, since I have to write the fields twice for the fixed length record class, but at least I don't have to write some of the attributes twice and save myself some mapping code.

By the way, I should be using at least autoproperties, but the limitations of FileHelpers means I can't because I need to use Custom Converters.